# Why does my desktop showing white outlines like this?

Tags: appearance

Why does my desktop showing white outlines like this?

I am facing this problem very lately.

[image]

Comment: Take a screenshot & check it on a different computer - or post it here. If the screenshot is clean, it's a hardware issue.

Comment: Additionally, how is the screen connected? VGA, HDMI, Display port? If it turns out to be a hardware issue, you should try a new cable.

Comment: It resembles stuck pixels on the LCD screen... if @Tetsujin's suggestion confirms it's hardware related, try a different input cable, as well as a different input method and input source - if a different input source results in the same/similar, you can try to get the pixels to unstick themselves by playing a specific looping video that loops all color hues with differing fractal shapes (you can find a myriad on YouTube) for ~24hrs.  This can sometimes get pixels to unstick themselves, otherwise you'll need a new monitor/LCD screen as those pixels are likely permanetly damaged.

Comment: You can very simply check for stuck pixels [which that doesn't look like anyway] Move the window containing that image. If the corruption follows, it's not stuck pixels. If it follows but is not absolutely identical, then we're back to the screenshot test - probably hardware fail.